# how do I put code of files into separate memory regions with the GNU Linker

Tags: linker, gnu, ld, linker-scripts

I am trying to use the linker script (LD) in order to split my code into 2 different MEMORY regions. 
i.e. - all code should go to MEM1 region. and only file2.o should go to MEM2 region.

```
MEMORY
{
    MEM1           : ORIGIN = 0x00000000,          LENGTH = 100K
    MEM2           : ORIGIN = 0x00800000,          LENGTH = 100K
}


SECTIONS
{
    .text    : { *(.text .text.*) } >MEM1
}
```

how do I exclude file2.o from going to MEM1 and direct it to MEM2?
I have tried using EXCLUDE_FILE (for file2.o and MEM1 region) without success.

any help/directions will be helpful

thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the LD manual, [3.6.4.2 Input Section Wildcard Patterns](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Input-Section-Wildcards.html):

> If a file name matches more than one wildcard pattern, or if a file name appears explicitly and is also matched by a wildcard pattern, the linker will use the **first match** in the linker script.

Have you tried something like this?

```
.text2 : { file2.o(.text .text.*) } >MEM2
.text  : {       *(.text .text.*) } >MEM1
```

However, this should work too:

```
.text  : { *(EXCLUDE_FILE(*file2.o) .text .text.*) } >MEM1
.text2 : { file2.o(.text .text.*) } >MEM2
```